# PHP return Division by zero

Tags: php

I've a function in php, this is the function

```
public function actionGetTotal($id){
    $month = date('m');
    $year = date('Y');
    $arrayDataMitra = Yii::$app->db->CreateCommand("SELECT nilai FROM data WHERE MONTH(first_date) = '$month' AND YEAR(first_date) = '$year' AND idMitra = '$id' AND idProgram BETWEEN '7' AND '11'")->queryAll();
    $arrayNilai = array_column($arrayDataMitra, 'nilai');

    $countArr = count($arrayNilai);        
    $totalPoin = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $countArr; $i++){
        $totalPoin = $totalPoin + $arrayNilai[$i];                            
    }

    $totalPoin = $totalPoin / $countArr; //issue
    return $totalPoin;
}
```

if I printout as `echo $totalPoin . ', ' . $countArr; die();` it will show **4, 2**. But if I delete it, the function return **Division by zero**. It said the $countArr is 0. Anyone can explain why it happen?

Thanks

> Update

If I do

```
$countArr = count($arrayNilai);        
echo '<pre>';
echo 'This is data array';
echo '<br>';
print_r($arrayNilai);
echo '<br>';
echo 'This is array count';
echo '<br>';
echo $countArr;
die();
```

it return

```
This is data array
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
)

This is array count
2
```

> UPDATE
>   I think it's not the function logic error. I'm using Yii2 framework, and that function called inside the gridview in **index.php**. The cause is I've 3 rows of data where only a row that contain data. That's why the `$countArr` is 0, because in second row there is no data from the `$arrayNilai`.
>   Thankyou

Comment: If you add `die()`, it ends the program. Without it, the function completes successfully but it is probably called again and on a subsequent call `$arrayNilai` is empty, consequently `$countArr` is `0`.

Comment: I get error when I didn't used the `die()`; Thankyou for commenting, yours open my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the query return no data. It leads to division by zero. What would you expect the result to be in such case? Maybe zero? You have to handle this situation explicitly. Like

```
if ($countArr===0) return 0;
```

Or dont call the entire function at all, if there is no data.

Comment: There is a data. That's why there's no error in the looping.

Comment: oh wait you are trying to print the slash, instead of it being division operator? then just concatente it like you comma example that is working: echo $totalPoin . '/' . $countArr;

Comment: No, I use the slash as operator. if I change the `$countArr` with static int, the function work well. So I'm sure the issue is in the `$countArr`

Comment: show me the output including error of your entire function and place var_dump($arrayDataMitra); //right after the line where it is assigned
var_dump($arrayNilai); //right after the line where this is assigned
and 
var_dump($countArr); //right before the division line

Comment: I've updated and show the output data. Isn't it enough?

Comment: No it's not. Only way for "division by zero" error to appear is, well, division by zero. Your example output does not contain zero, so it is not the case when error is thrown. I want to see complete example, what gets dumped just before the error occurs. Just as axiac wrote, it may be that the function gets executed multiple times inside your script but you are only looking on the first execution which may be fine, but some of the fllowing calls is not.

Comment: No problem, btw, there still is a function logic error. You really should apply what i described in my original answer here.

Comment: Yes, off course. I've added the conditional for the `$countArr`. Thankyou :D

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 4,2. It will be 4 or 2. 
I think you had miss here to concatinate like
$totalPoin = $totalPoin + $arrayNilai[$i];

will be $totalPoin .= $totalPoin + $arrayNilai[$i];

try to handle error handling here. You can do by using @ with variable name.

Comment: No, I echo two variable, so the ouput 4, 2. The result of `$totalPoin = $totalPoin + $arrayNilai[$i];` is right.The issue is why it said the `$countArr` is zero in the line I give tag `//issue`. @ with variable name? Can you describe?

Comment: "@" operator is to be used by lazy and irresponsible developers. And in some cases, by those who are forced to use code created by those lazy, irresponsible developers...

Comment: example of use of "@"? rather not, since you are probably beginner, I won't introduce you a feature that is better avoid at all costs...

Comment: Yeh you're right. It's better if I avoid it. Thankyou somuch for telling :)